# Programmatically binding with NeedDatasource?

Tags: c#, telerik, treelist

First Issue,I have two controls (a radcombox and a Treelist controls) on my page. On radcombobox's SelectedIndexChanged I am populating data from database.Now I want to fire NeedDatasource event on SelectedIndexChanged. How  could I do that ?

Second issue,

As I am facing some issues with needdatasource, I have manually binded using databind method of radtreelist.After binding it shows only parent nodes at first.

After clicking on PageSize combo of RadTreelist, it loads with respective child nodes.Why is this happening here ?

```
  <telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcb_testtype" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rcb_testtype_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                <Items>
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Select a Test Type" Value="-1" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Practise Test" Value="pt" />
                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem runat="server" Text="Normal Test" Value="nt" />
                </Items>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>


 <telerik:RadTreeList ID="rtl_specific_topic" runat="server"
                ParentDataKeyNames="parent_topicid" DataKeyNames="topicid" AllowPaging="true" RenderMode="Classic" Skin="WebBlue"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" ExpandCollapseMode="Client" AllowRecursiveSelection="False" OnItemDataBound="rtl_specific_topic_OnItemDataBound"
                AllowMultiItemSelection="true" OnItemCommand="RadTreeList1_ItemCommand" OnPageSizeChanged="RadTreeList1_PageSizeChanged" OnPageIndexChanged="RadTreeList1_PageIndexChanged">

                <Columns>
                    <telerik:TreeListSelectColumn HeaderStyle-Width="38px">
                    </telerik:TreeListSelectColumn>

                    <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="parent_topicid" UniqueName="parent_topicid" HeaderText="Parent Topic Id" Visible="False">
                    </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="topicid" UniqueName="topicid" HeaderText="Topic ID" Visible="False">
                   ion" UniqueName="description" HeaderText="Topic Name">
                    </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
                    <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Weightage" UniqueName="syllabus_weightage" HeaderStyle-Width="95px" ItemStyle-Width="95px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="rntb_weightage" MinValue="0" Width="80px" MaxValue="100" EmptyMessage="weightage(%)" AllowRounding="true"></telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Weightage" UniqueName="quest_category">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_quest_category" runat="server" Width="100px" style="right: 1px;">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="select a question type" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Multiple Choice" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="True/False" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Essay Writing" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Pictorial" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Short Question" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="90px"></HeaderStyle>
                    </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
                    <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn HeaderText="Set Level" UniqueName="level">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadSlider runat="server" ID="rs_level" Skin="Web20" Width="490px" AutoPostBack="True"
                                Height="70px" CssClass="dragRangeSlider" EnableServerSideRendering="true" IsSelectionRangeEnabled="true" OnValueChanged="rs_level_OnValueChanged"
                                EnableDragRange="true"
                                ItemType="Item">
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadSliderItem Text="L1" Value="1" runat="server"></telerik:RadSliderItem>
                                    <telerik:RadSliderItem Text="L2" Value="2" runat="server"></telerik:RadSliderItem>
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadSlider>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle Width="490px"></HeaderStyle>
                        <ItemStyle Width="490px"></ItemStyle>
                    </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
                </Columns>
            </telerik:RadTreeList>
```

OnSelectedIndexChanged bind radtreelist

in Code behind

```
protected void rcb_testtype_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        rcb_syllabus_name.Visible = rcb_testtype.SelectedValue != "pt";
        rtl_specific_topic.DataSource = FetchTopicDetailsForSyllabus(); 
        rtl_specific_topic.DataBind();
    }

     private DataTable FetchTopicDetailsForSyllabus()
    {
        DataTable dtTopocsForTest = null;
        if (rcb_testtype.SelectedValue == "nt" && rcb_syllabus_name.SelectedValue != "")
        {
            obj_BEL_LMS.Flag = "normaltest";
            obj_BEL_LMS.Syllabusid = Convert.ToInt32(rcb_syllabus_name.SelectedValue);
            dtTopocsForTest = obj_BL_LMS.FetchSyllabusDetails(obj_BEL_LMS);
        }
        else if (rcb_testtype.SelectedValue == "pt")
        {
            obj_BEL_LMS.iFlag = 2;
            obj_BEL_LMS.iBranchId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["branchid"]);
            dtTopocsForTest = obj_BL_LMS.FetchTopicDetailsDb(obj_BEL_LMS);
        }
        return dtTopocsForTest;
    }
```

After binding it shows only parent data.

Answer (score 0):

From the Telerik documentation:

> This event fires in the following cases:
>
> - Right after OnLoad, Telerik RadTreeList checks the viewstate for stored TreeList-related information. If such information is missing (when the page loads for the first time), the NeedDataSource event is fired. This also means that if the EnableViewState property of the control  has been set to false, the treelist will bind each time the page loads (not only the first time)
> - After expand/collapse
> - When paging event occurs
> - When other operations requiring Rebind occurs
>     The advantages of using this event are that the developer does not need to write any code handling the logic about when and how the data-binding should be processed. It is still the developer's responsibility to construct properly a data source object and assign it to the RadTreeList's DataSource property.
>     In the code of the NeedDataSource handler you should prepare the data source (list of objects) for Telerik RadTreeList and assign it to the grid's DataSource property. Also you should set the DataKeyNames and ParentDataKeyNames propertied for the TreeList control.

**Note: You should never call the DataBind() method from inside the NeedDataSource handler or mix simple data-binding mode with advanced data-binding**

I suggest you edit your post and include your code.